# Is “$\mu_{\bar{x}} = \mu$” the same thing as saying the mean of the population is the same as the mean of the sample?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, population

My e-textbook is telling me that, when finding a sample from a population using a normal probability distribution $\mu_{\bar{x}}$ is roughly equal to $\mu$. It then gives me a problem asking me to find the probability that the sample mean is 110 given that the parent population's mean = 100 and the standard deviation = 15. I thought, "surely the probability is 0, since the population and sample mean should roughly equal each other," but this is clearly not the correct thinking, as evidenced by the video in the textbook giving a completely reasonable explanation and solution of 2%. I'm clearly missing some crucial information, or the textbook just worded the explanation and question strangely.

Comment: Can you provide the name of your e-textbook?

Comment: Pearson MyLab "Interactive Statistics: Informed Decisions Using Data, 2/e" By sullivan and woodbury. ISBN-13: 9780134674902
This particular instance was in chapter 8.1

Comment: Is $\mu_{\bar{x}} \equiv E(\bar{X})$? (where $\bar{X}$ is the sample mean)

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't learned what E() is used for yet, so I couldn't tell you. And thank you for the edit.

Comment: They're indexing $\mu$ with the the random variable $\bar{X}$ whose mean it's representing. So, basically, $\mu_{\bar{X}}=\mu$ is saying the expected value of the random variable $\bar{X}$ is $\mu$. You could aleo say $\sigma_{\bar{X}}^2=\sigma^2/ n$

Comment: @MatthewHolder That sort of makes sense, but I'm still kind of missing the point. I suppose I'll wait until tuesday when I can meet with my professor on zoom, since she has experience with the material, and can explain in speaking.

Comment: @CameronFowlks can you check to make sure that you've copied the text properly. I use a similar textbook by Sullivan and in section 8.1 there is an example that seems similar to that you write about. The example computes the probability that the sample mean is **greater than 110** for a sample size of 10, which turns out to be approximately 2%.

Comment: @SOULed_Outt It does in fact say probability that it is greater than 110, not that it is exactly 100. I understand the process to do the type of problem, but the way they worded the definition/practice problem is so problematic to me. How can they tell me that the sample mean must equal the population mean and then tell me to find the probability that the mean is something that is not that of the population? I realize I just misinterpreted something and I am incredibly thick in the head, but this is a sincere question.

Comment: I have discovered where I went wrong. the e-text page says that the mean of the **sampling distribution** is “$\mu_{\bar{x}} = \mu$”, not that the sample's mean itself will be equal to that of the population. It turns out I just misread the page while working at 1 am.

Comment: After getting to speak with my professor, I really did just terribly misread. I didn't realize that $\mu_{\bar{x}}$ was the average of all possible averages of the population, and instead thought it was asking me the probability that $\mu_{\bar{x}}$ was different from $\mu$ (such that the values of the samples you took determined $\mu_{\bar{x}}$ ) Sorry to cause any confusion.

Comment: @CameronFowlks - If you have an answer to this question, it may be useful to add it so the community could benefit from it.

Comment: I would do that, but it would amount to me saying I'm an idiot that can't read, and explaining what I didn't understand but now do. Does that sound like a reasonable answer?